# How to allow ONE app to run while Mac is locked/sleeping?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, sleep-wake, apple-silicon

I want one app, Google Drive Backup and Sync, to be allowed to run in the background at all times. However, to save power I don't want this to apply to other apps since they should sleep while the computer is closed.

I'm aware I can go into settings and allow background apps to run while the Mac is sleeping, but unless this is configurable I don't think it would be a good fit.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean with "application should run while Mac is sleeping", somehow this seems to be a contradiction?

Comment: @nohillside There is a setting which allows this exact thing, but it applies globally and I don't want this behavior. On android phones, even if the screen is off and the phone is locked, background processes can still run at full power.

Comment: On iOS devices, this is not allowed. Now on Mac a setting can be configured to make macOS behave more like Android. I want this behavior but I want to be able to configure it to only apply to certain apps.